# I am having trouble pasting data from one cell to another

Tags: excel, copy, cell, paste

I am having a problem using VBA to copy and paste to a certain cell.  It works for these cells -

- `Range("D2") Copy .Range("C21")`
- `Range("E2") Copy .Range("C22")`
- `Range("F2") Copy .Range("C23")`

But not for this cell -

- `Range("G2") Copy .Range("C24")`

There is no error message, it just doesn't paste. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here several ways:
1.You could make a copy of the Excel, delete what is not relevant and distribute it here. If the error still exists we have a look.

2.An other way is to do the copy-paste manually and record it as a Makro. Then execute the recorded code.
And If you can‘t do it manually, then check if the cells and the sheet are protected.